# "Failed - Network error" message when exporting data to Excel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, google-chrome

I am trying to export data to excel file asp.net mvc using the Response.ContenType approach. Below is my code:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append("<table><tr><td>");
 //some code to convert database records to html table in stringbuilder

 Response.Clear();
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.ClearHeaders();
 Response.Charset = "";
 Response.Buffer = true;
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserReport.xls");
 Response.Write(sb.ToString());
 Response.Flush();
 Response.Close();
```

This code is working on my local pc but on server it is not working. On server i am getting "Failed - Network error" on chrome browser. [image]

If I do not put Response.Clear(); and Response.Close(); as said in other similar answers. The excel file is wrongly generated. See the below image.[image]

**Update:** I checked it on other browsers and found out that it is working on IE and Firefox but on Chrome it is now working. So why chrome is not behaving like other browsers ?

Comment: avoid  Response.Clear() and Response.Close()

Comment: @jas its not working. In my local PC my code is working but now on server. Why?

Comment: Have you want to return XLS(X) file from the stream? Note that Excel file format uses binary data instead of text, you may need `Response.BinaryWrite` followed with `Response.End`.

Comment: <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xslx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

OR

<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension="xls"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension="xls" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel"/>
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>

I think you need to add mime type to web.config for IIS

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Response.BinaryWrite() does not take string parameter. So how to apply it. My solution is working on local pc but not on server. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension="xls"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension="xls" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel"/>
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

OR

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xslx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Check your MIME-Types in IIS  the webserver is not aware of the Office 2007 and higher file extensions and refuses to serve them.

Comment: unfortunately after adding the mine, it is still now working.